# supertest passing new ObjectId as string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, supertest, objectid

I am writing an express routing test with mongodb.
Somehow while testing the post endpoint to create a task, it sees new `ObjectId('blah')` as a string.

my test looks like

```
  const testTask = {
    "_id": new ObjectId("61216a421cdd420a859051ca"),
    "name" : "Test Task Create",
    "date" : new Date(),
    "is_deleted" : 0,
    "is_done" : 0
  };

  test("POST /task/add", async () => {
    await supertest(app).post("/task/add")
      .send(testTask)
      .expect(200)
      .then((response) => {
           console.log(response);
      });
  });
```

If I create the same object and use it in my actual routing, it does create the _id as new ObjectId though.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in the testing while posting?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** have to add the following in your code

```
.post("/task/add")
```